# reducing data that are very close to one another in matlab to get one set of data

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to perform image analysis to get the boundary of an image.  The problem is, there is an overlap of more than one point on the data. The problem occurs due to the pixel width of the boundary. ie, my algorithm reads the image, and because the boundary is thick, I get multiple ( sometimes 2 or 3) data points that represent the boundary .As you can see in the image, I have analysed an image and have the scatter plot showing the coordinates.  The boundary has more than one element representing it. I need to reduce my vectors (of coordinates) such that a boundary is represented by only one line. I attach the code along with the question for your reference. I am doing this so as to get one single data that can represent the whole image.

```
clc;close all;
clear all;
folder = 'C:\Users\Adi\Desktop'; % image folder
baseFileName = 'part8.jpg';
% Get the full filename, with path prepended.
fullFileName = fullfile(folder, baseFileName);
rgbImage = imread(fullFileName); % read the image
% Get the dimensions of the image.  numberOfColorBands should be = 3.
[rows, columns, numberOfColorBands] = size(rgbImage);
figure;
greenChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 2);
   binaryImage = greenChannel < 200; % convert image to BW
   imshow(binaryImage);
i=1;
j=1;
data=zeros(rows,columns);  
n=1;% sample every n rows or col of the image
img2=zeros(rows/n,columns/n);
for col=1:n:columns                  %reducing the size of the image
    for row=1:n:rows
        if(binaryImage(row,col)==1)
%         data(row,col)=1;
        x(i)=row;
        y(i)=col;           % locate where the image is present
       img2(x(i),y(i))=1;
       i=i+1;
        end
      end
end
figure;
scatter(x,y);
figure;
imshow(img2);
blankImage=zeros(length(1:rows),length(1:columns));
m=1; % counter variable
for k=2:rows-1
    for l=2:columns-1
        if((binaryImage(k+1,l)==0)&&(binaryImage(k,l+1)==0)&&(binaryImage(k-1,l)==0)&&(binaryImage(k,l-1)==0)&&(binaryImage(k,l)==0))
%             % if all surrounding pixels are black, ignore them
            blankImage(k,l)=0;
            elseif((binaryImage(k+1,l)==1)&&(binaryImage(k,l+1)==1)&&(binaryImage(k-1,l)==1)&&(binaryImage(k,l-1)==1)&&(binaryImage(k,l)==1))
            %if all surrounding pix are white ,ignore them
            blankImage(k,l)=0;
           else
            blankImage(k,l)=1; % get the boundary elements
            x_brep(m)=k;
            y_brep(m)=l;
              m=m+1; 
          end
      end
  end
  figure;
  imshow(blankImage);
    figure;
    scatter(x_brep,y_brep);
```

Sample image and output:
[image]

[image]

Comment: This question should not be tagged with the processing tag, because it has nothing to do with the Processing language.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the image processing toolbox, you can take your original image, and use `bwmorph` - for example, `thin` or `skel`, to reduce it to a single pixel line.  Note that you may need to invert your image (so that it is a white line on a black background).

Presuming your original image as shown is already binary and is stored in BW (but with line as black on white), it should be as simple as (`~BW` just inverts the image).

```
BW2 = bwmorph(~BW,'thin', Inf);
```

If your image is not already binary you will need to convert it to binary first.